# Does a compressor with a short to ground really require a complete system replacement?

Tags: hvac, compressor

My 24 year old home A\C went out some time Sunday morning. I had a tech come out and look at it, and was told that the compressor is shorted to ground, and that this means I have to replace the entire compressor and possibly the entire system.

I'm asking this community for a sanity check, since I know nothing about HVAC systems. Is a "compressor shorted to ground" really a "replace the whole kit and kaboodle" situation? Or is more information needed to reach that conclusion?

Comment: They want to replace the entire system - inside and out.

Comment: 24 years - it's the original system put in when the townhome was built in 1989. So yes, I've known a full system replacement was coming, I was just hoping to squeak out a few more years before it got here...

Comment: The time has come, but don't feel so bad. You'll probably end up with a more efficient system, which will save you a bit in operating costs.

Comment: Oh it'll definitely save me in operating costs. The install cost is what's killing me - especially as I bought a not-quite-as-badly-needed new car 3 months ago.

Comment: Just to answer your literal question, compressors are not field serviceable. If your compressor has a problem, the only option is to replace it.

Comment: Fried field windings on a sealed motor. 24 years old? Yes. Been there on this one. Your compressor system needs to match your evaporator system, (the unit inside the house) if we're dealing with a two part system, it's probably no longer available in a matching set.

Comment: Final result: the compressor is just fine. The first tech didn't bother to examine the whip, which was shorted phase-to-phase just as it exited the disconnect box. Roughly $350 later, everything is back in working order. (Yes, I'm still planning on a complete replacement in the next 3-5 years.)

Answer (score 3):

The compressor is the "engine" of the AC system.  It, and a few valves, and the condenser fan, comprise all the active portions.  Everything else is passive.    The compressor is an electrical motor connected to a precision pump.  The pump has to be lubricated by sufficient refrigerant (Freon or substitutes).  If a compressor seizes, it may burn out the electrical motor, causing the electrical windings to short out.

Long story short, a failed compressor may be a reason for system replacement.  You would be well advised to get a second opinion from another contractor.  Get quotes for both repair and replacement.

Another reason to replace the system, is the [mandated phase-out of R22 refrigerant](http://www.epa.gov/ozone/title6/phaseout/22phaseout.html).  If your system is older than 5 years, it probably uses R22.  While an existing unit doesn't need to be replaced, per se, because of the phase out, practically, it will, due to the price of the refrigerant.  I just paid $5/ounce for my system recharge.

[image]

Comment: It's 24 years old, and yes it does use that horrendously expensive R22 refrigerant. I'm not looking forward to paying $11k (the first quote of at least 3 I'll be getting) for a new 3 ton system...

Comment: At that price, you may want to look at a geothermal heat pump (with ground sourcing).  The install costs are high, but operating costs are usually much lower. Look here: http://www.qualitysmith.com/request/articles/articles-hvac/geothermal-heat-pump-cost/

Comment: Geothermal probably isn't a viable option for me since I'm in a townhome, not a single-family. The HOA might not like that idea.

Comment: In that case, pitch it as a high efficiency upgrade for all the units.  Common wells are possible, though not universally acclaimed over individual wells. You'd need an experienced contractor/HVAC design firm to make the pitch/proposal.  Joint system maintenance would get rolled into the annual maintenance fee.   Just sayin...

Answer (score 2):

If your compressor is shorted to ground, its almost likely contaminated the whole refrigerant circuit. The age of your A/C has a lot to do with you should replace the whole system. I would recommend total A/C replacement, the only time that I would even recommend just a compressor change out, if the compressor is under warranty. Plus the new system will be more efficient, and if you can afford it, replace the furnace with a 95 plus high efficiency furnace. It will pay for itself in 5 years, if you are getting rid of a 80% furnace.  I recommend Trane or American Standard.

Answer (score 0):

If the compressor is measured at the compressor connector pins under the connector cover with the conductors (wires) removed and any point reads to ground or any resistance less than infinity, the compressor is fried, dead, gone.

Answer (score -2):

All this high efficiency stuff is nonsense. What you should be considering is operating costs. Stick with low tech. The high efficiency models will cost you more upfront and since they’re more complex they’re more prone to failure (greater complexity = More things that might fail!). Also the cost of replacement components for the high efficiency models will be more than the low tech equivalent. Saving a few dollars on your utility bill will be dwarfed by the repeated servicing costs of your local HVAC tech.

Comment: As it's written, this Answer doesn't really address the Question and reads like a comment to some of the other Answers that suggest replacement with High Efficiency. If you take the [tour] you'll find out more about how Questions, Answers and Comments should be organized.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/147414)

Comment: Modern units aren't just more efficient -- they can *modulate*, throttling back their output under part load (which is very helpful in cool-but-humid conditions to allow effective dehumidification without overcooling the air), and in heat pump form, are much more capable of running in cold weather than "classical" North American units are

Comment: Also, in the year 2022, there is absolutely no reason whatsoever to buy an air-conditioning-only outdoor unit for a residential application.  (Heat pumps, even when running in a crippled forced-air dual-fuel setup, *still* provide quite a bit of useful heating capacity, especially during "shoulder seasons" where you don't need the full power of your furnace to heat the house)